# Pip install yfinance, conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, yfinance

I am a new user of anaconda / python / spyder. I am trying to install `yfinance` library via Anaconda's base(root) terminal.

[Yfinance](https://anaconda.org/ranaroussi/yfinance)

Pip command:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/simple yfinance
```

When I run, I get several notifications that things are downloading and requirements have been satisfied, but then I get the linked set of error messages. I reviewed the pip user guide for fixing conflicting dependencies but was not coming up with much - and granted, I'm pretty new to this language and delivery system. Any suggestions? Are others getting the same error?

Error Messages Screencap:
[image: Error Messages Screencap]

Comment: What if you enter `conda install -c ranaroussi yfinance`? According to the [official repository](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance#installation), you should enter `pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir` if you would like to install it using pip.